# Замена повторяющихся символов с помощью регулярных выражений

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Возможно ли заменить в слове все повторяющиеся символы одним с помощью регулярного выражения?
Максимум повторений символа равно двум.
Разобрался как удалить заранее известный символ (например `s{2}`), но по аналогии сделать не вышло.

---

## Пример:

**Input:** success, book, read

**Output:** suces, bok, read

Comment: примеры входов и выходов? Покажите также код, что сами пробовали

Comment: success на выходе должно выйти suces
Разобрался как заменить заранее известный повторяющийся символ, например для замены двойной буквы c Regex r = new Regex(@"c{2}");
Пробовал сделать по аналогии Regex r = new Regex(@"[a-z]{2}");, но понял, что он ищет любые последовательности из двух символов.

Comment: @Exirel, `(.)\1` replace `$1`

Comment: @Let'ssayPie забыли одну мелочь - `(.)\1{1,}`

Comment: @Let's say Pie, благодарю, про группы не подумал

Comment: @Exirel, вот простой пример: https://ideone.com/8AwNe0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace("success", @"(.)\1+", "$1"));    
    }
}
```

Comment: @rdorn, да, это я погорячился...